# Java application connection to the internet blocked when using a different WiFi

Tags: network, wifi, java, firewall

I am using dBeaver to connect to some databases that are at AWS.

From home this works fine, but when I connect to my mobile hotspot these databases time out when connecting.

First I assumed that these were some AWS security settings, because I was on a different IP. But then I found that when I startup a command prompt I can connect using `psql`, so this means that it is a local problem. I have a different application that uses jdbc to connect to the database, and that application also has the same behavior.

Anyone know where this traffic might be blocked, or how to find out where? I already tried disabling the Mac Firewall, but that gave no positive result.

System: Apple M1 Pro - Ventura

Comment: My first guess would be your mobile provider as home connection works

Comment: It cannot be my mobile provider, because I can connect from the terminal. Both are wifi connections. So my guess is some network security settings for java that are blocking it.

Comment: OK then the next thing is the jdbc connection string - try a minimal java executable to connect

Comment: Could it be a DNS issue? Different network different DNS servers? Can you connect to the IP?

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out!

I had installed [UTM](https://mac.getutm.app), which was doing some network bridging that was in the way. After uninstalling it, network connections from Java applications work again!